# Suppose $\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$ is a basis for $R^{2}$ and $A$. Show $A$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose $\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$ is a basis for $R^{2}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$. If $\{a\vec{x} + b\vec{y}, c\vec{x} + d\vec{y}\}$ is a basis for $R^2$ show $A$ is invertible.

**My Attempt**

For every $\vec{v} \in R^2$ we must have a unique $k_1,k_2 \in R$ such that $ \vec{v} = k_1(a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}) + k_2(c\vec{x}+d\vec{y})$. Hence we can construct the matrix and equation $Ak=\vec{0}$, from the fact that $ \vec{v} = (k_1a+k_2c)\vec{x}+(k_1b+k_2d)\vec{y}$

$$A \vec{k}= \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix} \vec{k} = \vec{0}$$

By the invertible matrix theorem, if this system $rankA=2$ (because we have a unique solution) then the matrix $A$ must be invertible. QED.

Can anyone offer suggestions to improve this proof / point out inconsistencies?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by $A \vec{k} = \vec{v}$.

Comment: I have made an update that should clarify the system I am constructing please let me know what you think

Comment: I am not convinced by your approach. Plus, what is the vector $k$ in the displayed equation? Do you mean the vector $v?$ What does that accomplish, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your $R$ is the real numbers $\mathbb R.$ Consider a basis $\{x, y\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ and a real matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$ such that $\{ax + by, cx + dy \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2.$ Observe that it suffices to prove that $\det A$ is nonzero. On the contrary, if it were the case that $\det A = ad - bc = 0,$ then we would have that $$d(ax + by) - b(cx + dy) = adx + bdy - bcx - bdy = (ad - bc)x + (bd - bd)y = 0.$$ By hypothesis that $\{ax + by, cx + dy\}$ is a basis (and hence, the vectors $ax + by$ and $cx + dy$ are linearly independent), we must have that $d = -b = 0.$ Consequently, we have that $\{ax, cx\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2.$ But this is a contradiction. Explicitly, if $c = 0,$ then $cx = 0,$ and the zero vector cannot belong to a basis. On the other hand, if $c$ is nonzero, then $0 = ax - ax = ax - \frac a c (cx)$ shows that $ax$ and $cx$ are linearly dependent. We conclude therefore that $\det A$ is nonzero.